# How to read this div text into three separate variables

Tags: jquery

I am doing a data scrap on a website (with their permission )

So when i do so i am getting the following div as response from ajax call

```
<div class="tickerdata">
   8250.00 
   <span class="down"><img src="redarrow.jpg" alt="Down">&nbsp;6.50</span>
   <span class="down"><img src="redarrow.jpg" alt="Down">&nbsp;0.08%</span>
</div>
```

I wanted to read all the numbers into variables  that is

8250.00 , 6.50 and 0.08% into 3 different variables .

I have tried as

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var tickerdatalive = $('.tickerdata').text(); 
    var current_price = tickerdatalive[0];
    var change_points = tickerdatalive[1];
    var change_percent = tickerdatalive[2];
});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/p2ww0nef/

Could you please let me know how to read the values into variables ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code snippet.

```
    <div class="tickerdata">
        8250.00 
   <span class="down">
       <img src="redarrow.jpg" alt="Down" />&nbsp;6.50</span>
        <span class="down">
            <img src="redarrow.jpg" alt="Down" />&nbsp;0.08%</span>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tickerdatalive = $('.tickerdata').text();
            var test =  tickerdatalive.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').filter(function (v) { return v !== '' })
            var current_price = test[0];
            var change_points = test[1];
            var change_percent = test[2];
        });
    </script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshgoyani/p2ww0nef/6/)

Answer (score 1):

I would first normalize whitespace and then split the string on single space:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var tickerdatalive = $('.tickerdata').text();

        var arr = tickerdatalive.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').split(' ')

        var current_price = arr[0];
        var change_points = arr[1];
        var change_percent = arr[2];

    });
```

See your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2ww0nef/4/

Of course you might want to check array length before assigning values to variables.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to detach the children so you can read their text outside the dom and the only thing left in the main container will be the text for price

```
$('.tickerdata').each(function(){

    var $spans = $(this).children().detach();
    // children are gone so all that is left is text node
    var current_price = $(this).text().trim();   

    var change_points = $spans.first().text().trim();
    var change_percent =$spans.last().text().trim();

   console.log([current_price,change_points,change_percent]);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pm0g5trq/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use `.contents()` instead of `.text()`

```
$(function() {
    var tickerdatalive = $('.tickerdata').contents(); 
    var current_price = tickerdatalive[0];
    var change_points = tickerdatalive[1];
    var change_percent = tickerdatalive[2];
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/contents/

> Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, **including text** and comment nodes.

Updated [fidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2ww0nef/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you can trim text and split with whitespace.

```
var tickerdatalive = $('.tickerdata').text().trim().split(/\s+/g);
```

tickerdatalive  will be the array of text nodes.